# How to do ajax between javascript and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to do ajax to javascript and get a result by calling js function.
but I cannot get data.

I'm making TIZEN web application.
and I have web service on my server(asp).
I did ajax to my web but I got error.
As you can see, I Tried to debugging through console.log but any reasonable values not printed.

> app.js (90) :getAlarmData()
>
> app.js (153) :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST"
        , url: "serverIP/WebProject/WebContents/view/filename/function name"
        , data: null
        , contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        , dataType: "json"
        , async: false
        , success: function (jSonResult) {
       },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(error + "\n" + status + "\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

> app.js (90) :getAlarmData()
>
> app.js (153) :

Comment: Is your browser showing CORS error? I assume you're testing on a locally deployed version of your app and your serverIP is not that same as your application host

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do a function call on a file which is present on your server, you can't do that directly. You have to open a road on your server which return the result of your function.

You have to take look about communicate a single page application (SPA - Front end app) and your API (server side app).

For example :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST"
    , url: "serverIP/my/awesome/road/which/calling/my/function"
    , data: null
    , contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    , dataType: "json"
    , async: false
    , success: function (jSonResult) {
        console.log( jSonResult );
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(error + "\n" + status + "\n" + xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

For resume, you have to :

- Open a road on your server
- Return the result of your function in the call (jSonResult)
- Use it in the success callback

Comment: What does "Open a road on your server" means? There are no firewall blocking, and I can connect my web service on my PC.

Comment: You can learn about it here, it talking about express.js which is a library on node.js which help you for build a server http : https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html
As you can see in the documentation, you open an URL road "/" for example, you will call it with ajax and get the return in the success function.